# How to limit product/variant quantity using Shopify Plus Script Editor app?

Tags: ruby, shopify

I'm looking for help to limit product/variant quantity using **script editor app** in **Shopify Plus**. The goal is to only allow one quantity to be able to add to cart per checkout for some specific variant ids in different products.

Answer (score 5):

There is no supported API for this, but you can update the line item object instance variables directly:

```
line_item.instance_variable_set(:@quantity, max_quantity)
```

Comment: you saved my day, but where did you find that